# Assigning a name to variable using a string inside a function in R and save it

Tags: r, variables, namespaces

Within a function I create a variable which I want to save it to the disk with a name that will be passed to the function.

E.g.the code below creates a variable x and saves it within an rda object with a name passed to the function (in this case "my_variable").  But when the rda object is loaded in the memory the variable appears with the name x and not the name "my_variable".   :

```
string <- "my_variable"
my_function <- function(string){   
 x <- 1            
  save(x, file = paste0(string, ".rda"))   
}

my_function(string)

load("my_variable.rda")
```

What should I do to make it appear with the name "my_variable"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
my_function <- function(string){   
  assign(string, 1)
  save(list = string, file = paste0(string, ".rda"))   
}
my_function("my_variable")

load("my_variable.rda")
my_variable
```

Comment: Any reason for using assign here?

Comment: sure. It solves the question asked. its equivalent to my_variable <- 1, not string <- 1 which is the point.